# Difference with queries regarding BFS

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb

Could someone give me some hints about this? This query works:

```
match path=(n)-[*bfs..10]->(m) 
return path limit 1;
```

however I get a memory limit exceed exception with this one:

```
match path=(n)-[*bfs..1000]->(m) 
return path limit 1;
```

Shouldn't the second query result in the same path as in the first query? Considering the same dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should result in the same path, but it's probably not strange that it results in a memory limit exception. Depending on the size and type of your graph, having a limit of 1000 for the path length could eat up a massive amount of RAM as the number of paths generated rises considerably by raising the path length.